# Make an if/then statement utilizing a non present element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm using Python and I came across one problem. I'm trying to make a bot using selenium, and it's coming along nicely but I'm trying to use a non-present element to activate a function and I just can't figure it out

```
if (element) not present:
   (action)
```

I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either:

- Look for all element that match certain search criteria:

  ```
  if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(my_locator):
      # No element found here
  ```
- Catch an exception when searching for a single instance:

  ```
  try:
     webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector(my_locator)
     except NoSuchElementException:
         # No element found here
  ```

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm!